# Data Flow Flex Runner Fails on start

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I created a simple beam pipeline that looks like this

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline: 
   (pipeline | 'readFile' >> ReadFromText(..)
             | 'parseJson' >> beam.Map(json.loads)
             | 'convertToRow' >> beam.Map(lambda x: beam.Row(a=str(x['a'])))
             | 'sql' >> SqlTransform(""" SELECT a FROM PCOLLECTION """)
             | 'print' >> beam.Map(print)
   )
```

and followed the code examples provided here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates  to be able to run this as a flex template. This is the error that I see

```
FileNotFoundError: [Error 2] No such file or directory: 'java': 'java'
```

My (very limited) understanding is that the docker image created as part of the flex template just launches the job on Dataflow, so don't quite understand why it's complaining about java directory not being present. Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to install java into the [container image](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates#java_1), adding something like https://github.com/dockerfile/java/blob/master/openjdk-7-jre/Dockerfile#L11 to the dockerfile.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Installing java on the container fixed the issue :)